IntelIJ не видит класса ArrayList
пытаюсь сделать import java.util.ArrayList;
но IntelIJ выдает Cannot resolve symbol 'ArrayList', при нажатии Alt + Enter предлагает только создать свой ArrayList, при этом другие импорты работают без проблем
Настройки проекта:



IntellIJ у меня 2018 года, jdk стоит 23 версии

Попробуйте File -> Invalidate Caches

@Serodv не помогло, также как и переустановка jdk, проверка настроек проекта и настроек модуля, в чистом проекте такая же ошибка

@Mazl У вас ведь идея не видит и другие классы из пакета java.util, верно?  Скорее всего, дело всё-таки в настройках IDE / SDK. См. IntelliJ IDEA: "cannot resolve symbol" for String, System and other Java classes

@NowhereMan В Project и Modules указан один и тот же jdk, вкладку SDKs тоже проверил, просто не понимаю в чем может быть еще проблема, разве что скачать другой jdk, но я не знаю какой, сейчас стоит этот https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java23

А идея поддерживает эту последнюю версию Java? К примеру, здесь был вариант, когда старенькую идею пытались обрадовать плюшками от относительно нового JDK.  Имеет смысл отредактировать вопрос и показать, что и как у вас настроено.

@NowhereMan вопрос отредактировал, и действительно у меня стоит самый новый jdk на IntellIJ 2018 года, но как узнать какой jdk поддерживается я не знаю

Согласно справке от IntelliJ, версия 2018.3 поддерживала максимум Java 12, 2018.2 - Java 11 и т.д.  Попробуйте обновить саму IDE.
